# Django partial update

Tags: django, django-models

I have two threads, one which runs something like `update t set ColA=foo` and the other runs `update t set ColB=foo`. If they were doing raw SQL statements there would be no contention, but since Django gets and saves the entire row, a race condition can occur.

Is there any way to tell Django that I just want to save a certain column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `save` will update the entire row but Django has an `update` which does exactly what you describe.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: I've updated the link to use the latest stable version.

Answer (score 11):

Update old topic.

Now, we have update_fields argument with save:

> If save() is passed a list of field names in keyword argument
>   update_fields, only the fields named in that list will be updated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save

```
product.name = 'Name changed again'
product.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option to guarantee this is to write the raw SQL by hand by using [Manager.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) or [a cursor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) depending on which one is more appropriate.