# How to update only specific fields in django model?

Tags: django

I want to update only specific fields in my model.
This is my models.py

```html
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='teacher/images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    joindate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And this is my forms.py

```html
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']


class TeacherExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Teacher
        fields = ['phone', 'address', 'salary', 'status', 'image']
```

And this is my views.py

```html
def update_teacher(request, pk):
    teacher = models.Teacher.objects.get(id=pk)
    user = models.User.objects.get(id=teacher.user_id)
    form1 = forms.TeacherForm(instance=user)
    form2 = forms.TeacherExtraForm(instance=teacher)
    context = {
        'teacher': teacher,
        'user': user,
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = forms.TeacherForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        form2 = forms.TeacherExtraForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            user = form1.save(commit=False)
       
            user.save(update_fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username'])
            f2 = form2.save(commit=False)
            f2.status = True
            f2.save(update_fields=['phone', 'address', 'salary', 'status'])
            return redirect('Teacher:teacher_index')
    return render(request, 'Teacher/update_teacher.html', context)
```

Here I only want to update the first_name, last_name, email, username, phone, address, salary and status without affecting the password and image field. When I add the password and image field also, it works but I do not want to update password and image here.

Comment: Remove the fields from the `TeacherForm`.

Comment: Then how do I create password and image for teacher while adding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django partial update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528683/django-partial-update)

Comment: @sd077: you make two forms, one to create, and one to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in such situations, one makes *two* forms, one to *create* and one to *update*. Django itself for example has a [**`UserCreateForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) and a [**`UserChangeForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm). We thus can construct two additional forms:

```
class TeacherUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

class TeacherUpdateExtraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Teacher
        fields = ['phone', 'address', 'salary', 'status']
```

In the view, we thus then work with these forms:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update_teacher(request, pk):
    teacher = get_object_or_404(models.Teacher, pk=pk)
    user = teacher.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = forms.TeacherUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        form2 = forms.TeacherUpdateExtraForm(request.POST, instance=teacher)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            from2.instance.status = True
            form2.save()
            return redirect('Teacher:teacher_index')
    else:
        form1 = forms.TeacherUpdateForm(instance=user)
        form2 = forms.TeacherUpdateExtraForm(instance=teacher)
    context = {
        'teacher': teacher,
        'user': user,
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2
    }
    return render(request, 'Teacher/update_teacher.html', context)
```

Comment: I also believe that update_fields should work. Is there any wrong with the code above?

Comment: @sd077: the form will reject it if the password, image, etc. is required and missing. So the problem is *not* with `update_fields`, it is with the form that aims to do proper validation. The problem thus arises at `form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid()`

Comment: @sd077: likely not, since there is no default for `password` and `image`, and these are not `null=True` either, so what should a form do in that case? But I think you are solving the wrong problem. A form is designed to interact with the user, not a model. So instead of trying to "tweak" the model towards a user interaction, normally the form should do that. Models should not be designed towards a use-case, they should be designed to store and represent data properly for any application.

Comment: thanks for your answers. One last question please. What if I only want to update (or change) image for teacher from teacher profile. How do I update that?

Comment: @sd077: you make a form that only takes `image` as field, (and of course you pass `request.FILES` to the form). This looks a bit similar to the `SetPasswordForm` that also only changes the password: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have used d-none class for other field which i don't want to update

```
  ====Font End =====     
            <div class="row g-2 mb-3">
              <div class="col-md d-none">
                  {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
              </div>
          
                <div class="col-md">
                  {{ form.status|as_crispy_field}}
                </div>
            </div>
         
        ======Back End =======
```

class SingleObjUpdate(UpdateView):

```
model = ModelName
template_name = 'template.html'
form_class = FormName
```